# How to handling concurrency (multiple user edit same data) - VB.NET featuring MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, concurrency

I created a coffee selling system with VB.NET and MySQL as the database.

In that system, users can update their own information, such as first name, last name, BOD, etc.

However, multiple users may currently edit the same dataset at the same time, which I need to prevent.

Example :

HRD made a typo when adding a cashier's name and wants to change it, at the same time, the cashier wants to change it, too.

What I want to do here is to notify the cashier when he opens his data in edit mode that someone else is already editing his data, e.g. by displaying "Your data is being edited".

I read that I can do that with locking the table, row etc., however, many people said that is a BAD way to solve this problem.

I am looking for suggestions to alternative, code based solutions.

I do some search in my native language (Indonesian) and just a few people write this article and bring me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A good method for doing this is to store an updated_at  timestamp value on the row, and then retrieve that when you select the record for editing.

When you update, make it conditional on the updated_at matching.  If no rows are changed, return an error to the client that the record has been changed and give them the option to compare changes.  Try to avoid throwing all their changes away, that will drive your users crazy.

Comment: Hmm, so i think timestamp will become current answer, but i hope, i will have something to do without doing something with the database.

Comment: Generally the only good way to do this is to make some database changes.

Comment: I implemented the timestamp and user id but I still have a problem when users click on the same second to run an ajax that will create records on the DB. I end up with double records.